# Holding on a function for a specific time

Tags: javascript, jquery

so this is kind of a weird question

i am working on a project where i am required to Hold something off for a period of time using javascript, such as sending info to another page for example

but, i do not want that line of code executing untill Midnight

pseudo code
if(midnight){
do this
}

This is the simplest way i could explain what i am trying to do, i know setInterval only goes with milliseconds and its pretty difficult (well for me) to get it to run every day at 12am(midnight)

any suggestion & advice would be great, thank you !

Comment: Is the time period defined or it is dependent on other process?

Comment: sounds kind of fishy.  like it should be a cron on the backend.....unless its like some weird animation triggering at midnight each day.  basically, you can poll Date.now() and check for the midnight equivalent if you really need to do this.

Comment: Have you considered what happens if the user's (browser) computer time is out of date or for users in a different timezone?

Comment: Are you sure you want that code client side and not server-side? (I'm assuming you are working on a client due to the `jquery` tag). If the user is not using his browser at midnight nothing will happen. Also, if he changes the time of his computer he can pretend to be midnight every minute. Is there any security concern or it is just a fancy pure UI thing? If it need to be client side I would suggest querying the server for the time, which you can do every minute for instance.

Comment: there is no security concern since what i am working on is just a prototype, i couldnt think of a way to come up with this logic with jquery for the life of me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function getTimeLeftTill(targetTime){
    var time = new Date();
    var ms = (time.getSeconds() + (time.getMinutes() + time.getHours() * 60 ) * 60) * 1000
    return targetTime > ms ? targetTime - ms : 24 - (ms - targetTime);
}

function runAtMidnight(cb){
    var midnightMS = 24* 60 * 60 * 1000; //Midnight or whenever, e.g for midday its 12 * 60 * 60 * 1000
    var timeLeft = getTimeLeftTill(midnightMS);
    setTimeout(function(){
        cb();
    }, timeLeft);
}

/*
 * Example
 */

runAtMidnight( function(){
    alert('it\'s midnight!');
} )
```

Comment: thanks, this solution worked best, and its possible to test this by simply changing system time to midnight, great solution.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to start a process that will terminate at midnight (i.e return true). At time you trigger your doThis() process. Are you familiar with the JavaScript [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)? The idea of the time you can get from [this](http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_timing_clock) page.

Comment: Try to include a more self-sufficient answer. Link-only answers are not encouraged at SO

Answer (score 0):

You can use this which will run every midnight:

```
var a = new Date();
a.setHours(24);
setTimeout(function () {
    function atMidnight () {
        alert('It\'s midnight');
    }

    atMidnight();
    setInterval(function () {
        atMidnight();
    }, 86400000);//86400000 is ms in a day

}, (a.getTime()-new Date().getTime()));
```

Comment: thats awesome man, now if i am to test this, can i simply change my time to  midnight ?

Comment: alright, its lame that i cant test this right now since im not connected on the server, but going through it seems simple and pretty logical, i just thought there is something other than setInterval to use, anyway... thank you for your help sir !

Comment: @andy not really, but this will make sure to start it at midnight